# How to send infomation from localhost to my webapp?

Tags: javascript, proxy, localhost, apache

So in my JS web app, I open a popup window to an external website, which I cannot access because of security.  The site redirects to my localhost when the user is done interacting, and it now contains info in the header.  (http://localhost/authkey=12345).  Is there any way I can detect server side when I get a connection to localhost and transmit this information back to my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the remote website is redirecting you back to your own app, you can use its **GET** or **POST** values.

You mentioned **"server side"** - in case you want to use server-side scripting, you have to learn some languages like PHP or ASP.

If you only want to deal with basic the basic things, you can still use Javascript.

I know about two libraries that can help you in parsing URLs:

- [jsUri](http://code.google.com/p/jsuri/)
- [jQuery URL Parser plugin](https://github.com/allmarkedup/jQuery-URL-Parser) - in case you want to use jQuery.

If the remote website provides you **POST** information too, you will have to use server-side scripting to handle this data.

Just to know:

**GET** - the information in your URL, such as `authkey=12345`.

**POST** - Invisible to the client.